# How do I select this radio button on web page using the selenium-webdriver in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code:

```
<td valign="top">
    <a name="m_1530:C4HPE" id="m_1530:C4HPE"></a>
    <input type="radio" onmousedown="validateMouseDown(event);" onkeydown="validateKeyDown(event);" onclick="tealeafAddEvent(this, 'custom_checkbox_click','m_1530_C4HPE'); checkOnClick(event);" displayname="m_1530_C4HPE" value="C4HPE">
</td>
```

Comment: JeffC - This is not my code definitely. I just shared a snippet of a code from where I have to scrap the data. I am new into this that's why I posted here.  Thanks for your all help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
By.XPath(".//input[@type='radio'][@value='C4HPE']")
```

If you need more precision add other @name='value' attributes in same way

Answer (score 0):

browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio'][@displayname='m_1530_C2CES']").click()

This is working for me now.